# Sometimes git will track all remote git branches as local branches without me asking to. What happened?

Tags: git, branch, behavior

sometimes, git will spontaneously (during some, but not all, "pull" or "clone" operations) copy all of the remote branches of a repository into my local repository (and even set them all up to track the corresponding remote branches correctly). What causes this? Is there a way I can do this on purpose?

Answer (score 5):

If you just do a normal branch from a remote branch, it'll track by default:

```
git checkout -b somebranch origin/somebranch
```

means roughly the same thing as

```
git checkout -t origin/somebranch
```

You pretty much have to explicitly tell it if you don't want such tracking.

Comment: ok, yeah, but sometimes I track branches that I didn't ask for!

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's spontaneously creating tracking branches on a plain pull?  I don't know how to convince it to do that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am suggesting.

Comment: Can you reproduce this and show a script of what you did?  I wouldn't know how to do that without explicitly checking things out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the remote branch you want to track, you can just do:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

It will say something like:

```
Branch somebranch set up to track remote branch badges from origin.
```