# Can I easily update all local git branches from remote branches simultaneously?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have a git repository with (at present) three branches:

- `head` is the stable version  (not to be confused with git `HEAD`)
- `experimental` is experimental code; it's supposed to compile
- `norman` is my sandbox; code in it might be broken

The "master" git repo is on a file server that is backed up.  But I have replicas on a local disk, on a machine at home, and on my laptop.  (I'm prepared to write code any time, any where).

`git branch -a` shows:

```
  experimental
  head
* norman
  tufts/HEAD
  tufts/experimental
  tufts/head
  tufts/norman
```

the Tufts branches are the remote branches on the "master" repo.  The local branches are supposed to track; `git config -l | grep -w remote` says:

```
remote.tufts.url=linux.cs.tufts.edu:/r/ghc/git/experimental.git
remote.tufts.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/tufts/*
branch.experimental.remote=tufts
branch.head.remote=tufts
branch.norman.remote=tufts
```

Here's my question: **how do I update all local branches from their remote counterparts simultaneously**, using a single git command?
`git-fetch` doesn't quite do the trick; it updates what it knows about the contents of each remote branch, but it doesn't merge them into the local.  And apparently `git-pull` updates only the currently checked out branch.  I want to update all branches at once.  Can it be done?

(I'm not wild about

```
for i in `git branch | sed 's/^.//'`; do git checkout $i ; git pull; done
```

partly because it's not obvious to me what happens to modified files in my working directory while all this is going on, and partly because I'd need yet more shell code to save and restore the info about what branch I'm currently on.)

I found one (not very closely related) question:

- About [tracking remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415433/sometimes-git-will-track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches-without-me-ask/415542)