# How can I check the status of a remote Git repository?

Tags: git

I have a remote Git repository to which I can push/pull from a local repository via SSH.

I can use the Git `status` command to check the untracked/unstaged files in the local repository. How do I do the same with the remote repository?

Please note that I'm not looking at finding the differences between the local commit and the remote commit.

Comment: Do you want to check, what changes others had checked in / added?

Comment: If you can push to it, it should generally be a `--bare` repo, so there will never be any work done on it and `git status` over on the server should never have anything to report in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18760795/683080

Comment: @Viji Well, I'm interested in finding files that have not be staged yet on the remote repo. Changes that others have added would should show up in commit diff.

Comment: @torek How would I determine whether the remote repo is bare repo?

Comment: On the server, look at the repo.  If it consists of just the git directory, it's bare.  (Technically it's bare if `git config --get --bool core.bare` says `true`.  But it tends to be super-obvious: `ls` in a non-bare repo shows working files, `ls` in a bare repo shows what you see when you `ls .git` in a working tree.)

Comment: @torek Thanks for explaining this. Please add both your comments as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: How to compare a local Git branch with its remote branch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a Git remote repository, to which you can `git push` via SSH, it should generally<sup>1</sup> be a `--bare` repository (see the [description of setting up a bare repository on a server in the on-line Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-2.html)). A bare repository doesn't have any place in which to do any work on it. This means `git status` has nothing to report—in fact, if you have a bare repository and `cd` to it, you get an error message: it needs a work directory in order to report anything.)

The technical definition of a bare repository is one in which `git config --get --bool core.bare` prints `true`. I have a non-bare repository in `/tmp/t` to start, here:

```
$ cd /tmp/t; git config --get --bool core.bare
false
$ cd /tmp; git clone --bare t bare.t.git
Cloning into bare repository 'bare.t.git'...
done.
$ cd bare.t.git
$ git config --get --bool core.bare
true
```

But it's usually obvious from inspection: if your clone says that the origin is `ssh://some.host/some/dir/repo`, and you can `ssh some.host` and `cd /some/dir/repo` and `ls`, a "bare" clone looks much like the contents of the `.git` directory on the non-bare clone:

```
$ cd /tmp/t; ls .git
COMMIT_EDITMSG  ORIG_HEAD       description     index           objects
FETCH_HEAD      branches        gitk.cache      info            packed-refs
HEAD            config          hooks           logs            refs
```

vs:

```
$ cd /tmp/bare.t.git; ls
HEAD            config          hooks           objects         refs
branches        description     info            packed-refs
```

(The bare clone lacks a few of the files made doing ordinary Git work in the non-bare one, but they are clearly related.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It's possible to push to non-bare repositories—it's just a bad idea. If you look at your own non-bare clone's `.git/config` (or use the more official interface, `git config --get receive.denyCurrentBranch`), you will generally see something like this:

```
[receive]
        denyCurrentBranch = warn
```

The value here may be any of `refuse`, `true`, `warn`, `false`, or `ignore`. Most values set things up so that `push` is only accepted if the push is to some branch *other* than the "current" branch.

The problem here is ... well, suppose you're logged in on the server to which other people push. And lo and behold, you `cd /some/dir/repo` and there are all these work files.

It's quite tempting to `git checkout zorg`, edit the number of taxi drivers, and `git commit` the result. But what happens when someone else is editing the same branch elsewhere, and commits and then `git push`-es in the middle of you doing something similar?

If he/she finishes his/her push before you start your `commit`, you have kind of a mess. Normally, both of you do this on systems other than the server, and whoever pushes first "wins" and the other person gets a failed "non fast forward" push and knows to fetch-and-(merge-or-rebase) (`git pull` or `git pull --rebase` or whatever).

But you're already on the server, so you can't use the normal work flow. In fact, it's tough to keep the work tree up-to-date in the first place: you can do this with a hook, but if you have the hook `git reset --hard` to update the work tree, it throws away any work anyone was doing.<sup>2</sup>

It's easier to just avoid the problem entirely: decree that there is no work tree, and that this is to be a `--bare` clone.  All the temptations and problems vanish.

<sup>2</sup>At one job, I inherited a setup that did just that (`git reset --hard` in a post-receive hook, and also at six-hour intervals via `cron`). It caused a lot of confusion at least once every few months. Unfortunately, the server and directory paths were hard-wired lots of places, making it hard to fix, too (and this particular issue was low priority). We just lived with it.

<sub>(As requested in comments, this is the two comments in "answer" form. I've expanded them a bit since there is more space here.)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

`git fetch --dry-run --verbose` may show what you need.

Example:

```
# Before a remote update:
user@localhost:~/build/demo/myrepo$ git fetch --dry-run --verbose
From https://gitserver.local/git/myrepo
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master

# After a remote update:
user@localhost:~/build/demo/myrepo$ git fetch --dry-run --verbose
POST git-upload-pack (328 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 12, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From https://gitserver.local/git/myrepo
   83619a7..67ea28b  master     -> origin/master
```

Caveats:

- The exit code does not reflect your local repository being in sync with the remote repository; it only reflects on the action itself being successful or not.
- If your local repository contains newer changes than the remote repository, Git fetch still considers your local repository up to date. Maybe `git push --dry-run` helps for this case.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but I got here asking a similar question of Google. What I wanted to know is "where is my remote currently at in relation to my local master.

```
 git log
```

was what I needed.

```
commit 7bf74892162713b87a19c6194c8041c9bbf96552 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Andy Reilly <andy@blah.com>
Date:   Tue Nov 9 18:46:16 2021 -0800

fixed data validation lock on condition column in upload spreadsheet

commit 8462456d5fe6bcc11acbf89bca949f15faef0424 (training-db/master)
Author: Andy Reilly <andy@blah.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 8 12:28:02 2021 -0800

added todo for future setup

commit 1cf4a93d419c4ccc1d1f5ac9203edd2b9cefafa4
Author: Andy Reilly <andy@blah.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 8 11:15:56 2021 -0800

added uniqueness to tenant for category names so accidental rerun of initial setup does not create duplicates

commit 28f2d5a2c4ca869ebdb086696c97554587592e27 (multi-tenant/master)
Author: Andy Reilly <andy@blah.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 6 18:32:09 2021 -0700
```

So know I knew that my training server was one commit behind and my production server was two commits behind.