# Windows: how to check the status of all git repositories at once?

Tags: windows, git, status

**Introduction**

In order to check the status of git repositores, `git status` could be issued from the root of a repository.

```
C:\path\to\git_repositories\git_repo_1>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

If a directory consists of multiple, e.g. 50 git repositories

```
C:\path\to\git_repositories>dir

 Directory of C:\path\to\git_repositories

  .ssh
  git_repo_1
  ...
  git_repo_50
   0 File(s)
   51 Dir(s)
```

Nor

```
C:\path\to\git_repositories>git status .
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

neither

```
C:\path\to\git_repositories>git status ./.
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

is able to check the status of all repositories

**Question**

How to check the status of all git repositories at once?

Comment: To be honest I preferred the older form of the title, but for minor things like this it's probably not worth going back and bulk editing anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop that changes into each directory, does `git status` and then changes back up:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /ad /b') do cd %a & git status & cd ..
```

You need to double the percentages if you use this in a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do cd %%a & git status & cd ..
```

**Edit:**

As suggested by Cupcake, you could do this instead:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /ad /b') do git --git-dir=%a/.git --work-tree=%a status
```

This feels like a more robust and flexible solution (e.g. you could adapt it more easily to work with a list of paths stored in a text file).

Comment: Saving this command in a `status.bat file` into `C:\path\to\git_repositories>` and subsequently running it shows the status of all git repositories. Thank you.

Comment: @utrecht a better solution (instead of `cd` into each folder) is to simply tell Git where each repository is instead with `--git-dir=<path>`, like `git status --git-dir=<path>`. See the [official Git manual for details](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html#_options).

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure which solution would be faster, maybe the `cd` would actually be faster.

Comment: I goofed, if you're going to use `--git-dir` this way, then you also need to tell Git where the working copy directory is for each repository with `--work-tree=<path>`, so for example: `git --git-dir=project/.git --work-tree=project status`. Otherwise, Git will think the current working directory is the working copy, so you'll end up with incorrect results.

Comment: @Cupcake changing the content of the status.bat to `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do git --git-dir=%%a/.git --work-tree=%%a status` works as well. Thank you.

Comment: Using the `-C` key this becomes even shorter :  

`for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /ad /b') do git -C %a status`  

or for bash:   

`for a in */; do git -C $a status; done`  

In order to keep track on which sub-directory it is reporting on, I did the following:   

`for a in */; do echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'; echo $a; git -C $a status; done`

Answer (score 12):

I went with:

```
find . -name .git -execdir bash -c 'echo -en "\033[1;31m"repo: "\033[1;34m"; basename "`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`"; git status -s' \;
```

I think it's nicer because treats directories recursively.

Edited to show the name of the repo in a cleaner way.

Comment: Just checking, this wouldn't fetch, correct? So if there is new stuff on the remote then this wouldn't catch it?

Comment: Also important to note that with the -s flag git status will not show if, eg, you are behind the remote  by n commits (a main use case for me). My modified version of yours  is as follows:
 find . -name .git -execdir bash -c 'echo -en "\033[1;31m"repo: "\033[1;34m"; basename "`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`";git fetch; git status -s -b' \;

My only problem with it at this point is that the -b flag shows info even when up to date. With that fixed I would think this was perfect.

Answer (score 4):

If you are a kind of a tool-guy, you could use a little helper called [RepoZ](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ) I wrote recently (and still write).

I answered a [quite similar question in more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43769942/704281).

Here's a screenshot from the current development stage so hopefully you can see whether it seems helpful to you or not:

[image: RepoZ]

If you are wondering what that strings like `+45 ~403 -88` mean - they are condensed status strings telling you whether there are commits to fetch or push and whether there are added/modified/deleted files locally. More detail on the [project site on GitHub](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ)

Comment: Wonderful tool, consistent and easy to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Borrowed from [coderwall - git status on all repos in folder](https://coderwall.com/p/grmruq/git-status-on-all-repos-in-folder):

> ```sh
> find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '(echo {} && cd {} && git status -s && echo)' \;
> ```
>
> - `find .`  : to find everything in the current folder
> - `-maxdepth 1`  : so that it doesn't recurse into subdirs of the repos
> - `-mindepth 1`  : so that it skips the current directory (of depth 0)
> - `-type d`  : only find directories
> - `-exec sh -c`  : spawn a shell and give it a command
> - `'(echo {} && cd {} && git status && echo)'`  : the command given to the shell
> - `echo {}`  : echo the directory found by  `find`
> - `cd {}`  : cd into the directory found by  `find`
> - `git status -s`  : run the actual git status, with the  `-s`  (short) option
> - `echo`  : echo an empty line, for readability
> - `\;`  : semicolon to run shell for each of the found directories instead of passing them all to one shell as arguments

---

Also, you could make an alias in your bash_profile use the following with escaping to make it work:

```sh
alias gs_recursive='find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c "echo {}; cd {}; git status -s; echo" \;'
```

Comment: Nice answer! For those who got error running it on Command Prompt or PowerShell, it's because you need to run it on Git Bash instead

Comment: Note: Windows-specific answer, doesn't work on Linux (`find: missing argument to '-exec'`).

Answer (score 2):

As of [2.34 the `for-each-repo` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-repo) allows running git commands across a list of repos defined in a multi-valued config.

**Example config:**

```
[myRepos]
  repo = /full/path/without/expansion/repo1
  repo = ../can/be/relative/repo2
[alias]
  all = for-each-repo --config=myRepos.repo
```

Then you can run `git all status`.

Comment: Awesome tip!  Any ideas on how to generate the list of `[myRepos]` programatically?

Comment: This is really helpful - it looks like the repo list needs to be in global .gitconfig, is there any way to externalize the list of repositories?

Comment: It does not need to be in the global config; it just needs to be visible/accessible where ever you're trying to use the command or alias.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a system that is made up of numerous Git repositories, that is possibly a situation for which the Google `repo` tool was created: https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-repo/

If you find yourself writing scripts to distribute Git commands over these repositories, you should probably switch to `repo`.

`repo` works with an (unfortunately) XML file called the "manifest.xml" which specifies the Git repositories that are in the workspace. For each repo specifies which branch and commit should appear; you can use `repo` to "pin" the Git repositories to particular versions, or to track heads.

If you have a `repo` workspace then

```
$ repo status
```

then `repo` will do pretty much what you're asking for: iterate over the Git repos and give you a status.

Answer (score 0):

## Oof... git's design failed.

When I looked up this question, I was reminded of all the examples out there that use `cd` to jump into repos and then run git commands in there.

You need to use the options `--git-dir=` and `--work-tree=`

(Well... that's what I want to say anyway.)

When we use those options `--git-dir` is the `.git` directory in the repo and the `--work-tree=` value is the repo's root directory.

#### For example

Let's say we are in `C:\`, the repo we're interested in is at `C:\workspace\foobar`

To get it's status without doing barbaric `cd` manuevers:

```
git --git-dir=c:\workspace\foobar\.git --work-tree=c:\workspace\foobar\ status
```

or for the nice short status we all like.

```
git --git-dir=c:\workspace\foobar\.git --work-tree=c:\workspace\foobar\ status -s
```

So that's only a little more than double the typing, and we get to use some barely coherent git options.

## Now that we know the civilised way...

What's more we haven't lowered ourselves to virtually banging rocks together and typing...

```
cd c:\workspace\foobar; git status -s
```

Why would we ever do that.

*(seriously though, do the `cd`.  It's very rare to even find a script doing the `--git-dir/--work-tree` nonsense. It's extremely poor user service and has all the hallmarks of 0% design thought.)*

Now let's do reflog... (ok let's not.)