# Is it possible to do Git status for all repos in subfolders?

Tags: macos, git, bash, subdirectory

I've got a folder, which contains about 10 subfolders each containing a separate git repo. So something like this:

```
MainFolder/:
-- GitRepoA/
-- GitRepoB/
-- GitRepoC/
-- GitRepoD/
-- etc.
```

I often want to check whats going on, specifically I would like a command which lists the output for `git status` for all subfolders in which something has changed. Does anybody know a solution for this? (I'm on Mac OSX by the way).

Comment: Duplicate of [Check status of all git repositories at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352701/check-status-of-all-git-repositories-at-once). Seriously, like an **exact** duplicate.

Comment: Nevermind, that's the Windows solution, but I wouldn't be surprised if  someone else already asked for an OS X or a *nix solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 17):

If you need recursion (or will work as well if you don't):

```
find . -name .git -type d -execdir git status \;
```

For each directory named `.git` will execute `git status` from within the directory that contains it (`-execdir`). Wow, exactly what you want.

You can append `-prune` too so as to not go further in subdirectories of a git project to be more efficient (but might skip git submodules—I have no ideas how submodules work I never use them):

```
find . -name .git -type d -execdir git status \; -prune
```

Comment: it would be great to print the working directory before git status

Comment: Had the same issue. I ended up with `find . -name .git -type d -execdir sh -c 'pwd ;git status' \;`

Answer (score 6):

Iterate over each directory, and set the working directory and `.git` directory with the commandline options `--work-tree` and `--git-dir` respectively:

```
for x in *; do git --work-tree="$x" --git-dir="$x/.git" status; done
```

Comment: if you loose overview, which of subdirectories is show a warning, message etc: 
enhance the  with some echo output .. 

for x in *; do echo " " && echo "EXT:$x" && git --work-tree="$x" --git-dir="$x/.git" status; done

Answer (score 3):

I tried all of the suggestions here, and none of them really worked for me for various reasons.

So here's what I have in my profile and I use it pretty often.

```bash
gitr () {
  for f in $(find . -type d -name .git | awk -F"/.git$" '{print $1}');  do
    echo
    echo "................................ (cd $f && git $*) ........................................."
    echo
    (cd $f && git $*)
  done
}
```

Snippets in code files are easily loaded in bash with the "." command, for instance:

```
   . gitr.sh # file containing gitr() function, if not in a profile file
```

Then I can run

```
gitr status
```

And I get something like:

```
................................ (cd ./dir0 && git status) .........................................

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

................................ (cd ./dir1 && git status) .........................................

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

................................ (cd ./dir2 && git status) .........................................

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

................................ (cd . && git status) .........................................

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

or

```
gitr log -c 1
```

or

```
gitr rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git status **/* *
```

Where:

- **/* = Every file inside a subdiretory
- * = Every file in the root diretory

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '(echo {} && cd {} && git status -s && echo)' \;
```

It works recursively. You can change `maxdepth` and `mindepth` for your requirements

Answer (score 1):

This code will give the subdirectory a name and show a compact status:

```
ls | xargs -i sh -c 'echo _______ {} ______ && cd {} && git status -s -uno && cd .. '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script. Perhaps also just create it as a function and place in `.bash_profile`.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS=(GitRepoA GitRepoB GitRepoC AnotherRepoA)

for R in "${REPOS[@]}"; do
    echo "Checking repo $R."
    pushd "$R" >/dev/null && {
        git status
        popd >/dev/null
    }
done
```

Place it in the main folder and run

```
bash script_name.sh
```

If your repos are in uniform, you can just do some things like:

```
shopt -s nullglob
REPOS=(GitRepo{A..Z} AnotherRepoA)
```

Or perhaps just

```
shopt -s nullglob
REPOS=(*)
```

Just as a function:

```
function check_repos {
    REPOS=(GitRepoA GitRepoB GitRepoC AnotherRepoA)

    for R in "${REPOS[@]}"; do
        echo "Checking repo $R."
        pushd "$R" >/dev/null && {
            git status
            popd >/dev/null
        }
    done
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for every subfolder so that I don't have to manually define all folders?

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this by writing a shell script, [mgit](https://github.com/holygeek/vimrc/blob/master/bin/mgit), that reads a hidden file .mgit in the current directory which contains a list of folders that are individual git repositories. It does something similar to this:

```
$ for d in */; do git -C $d status; done
```