# Check the statuses of all my git repos in one go

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I work in an agency so we work on a lot of different projects and git repositories during the week.

I'd like to use git from the command line (rather than a GUI) but one thing I'm missing is a reliable, quick, easy way to see which of the repositories I've been working on I've forgotten to commit/push.

I can use `git status` and `git branch` on individual repositories which is helpful but this approach would take a while each time I just want to 'check all the things'.

**Is there a simple way to check all the git repositories' statuses from the command line in one go?**

In an ideal world I'd never forget to commit or push or fetch or pull but I know this isn't realistic.

I'm on OS X and my repository directories sit in a common 'Sites' folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check status of all git repositories at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352701/check-status-of-all-git-repositories-at-once)

Comment: Would a shell script solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following tools, they cover your use case quite well:

- http://mixu.net/gr/
- http://fabioz.github.io/mu-repo/
- https://github.com/esrlabs/git-repo

All of these allow you to manage multiple Git repos from command line, through means of bookmarking, tagging or configuration.

I have not used any of these, but `gr` looks pretty cool.

Comment: Ahh awesome thanks, i'll look through these in a little bit. I'd just worked out this one liner, but it's crude: `for dir in ./*; do (cd "$dir" && git status); done`

Answer (score 0):

The key to this answer is the command `git branch -vv` (double verbose), using this alone may give enough overview of a single repository whilst saving time. It will print the branches with their local statuses.

However,

I have currently settled on a combination of http://mixu.net/gr/ (thanks @nwinkler) and the command `git branch -vv`.

Once Gr is set up (tutorial on the site) you can use a combo command such as:

`gr @tag git branch -vv`

This will list all the repositories tagged in gr with their branches and their statuses.

I don't believe it will notify if there is anything to pull from remote repositories. Even so, the command `git branch -vv -a` will also list remote repositories.

With gr the complete command is `gr @tag git branch -vv -a`.