# Check status for Git repositories in other system

Tags: windows, git, github, gitlab

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352701/check-status-of-all-git-repositories-at-once) Question and able to get status for all `Git` folders in single system.

But is there any way to know the status of all `Git` repositories, that are there in other systems (Connected via same LAN)

Comment: Use `ssh` on Unix-based systems?

Answer (score 1):

Not natively with Git alone.

Similarly to "[Check status of all git repositories at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24352701/6309)", you would have to script such a "global status".
That script would have to be able to open a session (for instance through ssh), go to the root folder of the non-bare repository, and make a `git status` there.
That is what an [Ansible playbook with `command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/command_module.html) could do for instance, if you had to automate that on a large number of remote machines.